# Git local copy seems to have lost entire history

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

Apologies if my terminology is wrong, I am not that experienced with Git. I have a local repo from a github repo and after a power outage, it is now showing

```
HEAD as 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and every single file as marked for add. TortoiseGit is showing `FETCH_HEAD` as my only local branch even though I have several branches as well as master. The remote branch seems to remember what's going on - it has the remote URL for origin and a selection of recent branches.

I'm really nervous to just try doing anything in case it ruins everything as I have local (non-pushed) changes. Is there a specific term for this problem I can look up?

I'm using tortoise-git on Windows. I do have git command line installed but I do not really know anything beyond the very basics.

[image]

I should add, my unpushed changes are minimal - literally 2 files - as I had just done a push before the outage. So reverting to sync with the remote repo is just fine if that's easier than trying to recover local commits.

When I run `git fsck` I get:

> error: Invalid HEAD error: unable to unpack
>   071bf20e651e1ac9ea91821ee947786138f79156 header error: inflateEnd:
>   stream consistency error (no message) fatal: loose object
>   071bf20e651e1ac9ea91821ee947786138f79156 (stored in .git/obj
>   ects/07/1bf20e651e1ac9ea91821ee947786138f79156) is corrupt

When I run `git reflog` I get:

> fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

When I run `git reset --hard` it fails:

> fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.

Comment: Did you have uncommitted changes?

Comment: A few. I could take a copy of those files easily enough but I don't want to start from scratch if I can avoid it as it will lose me half a day downloading everything.

Comment: Did you try `git checkout master`? (I would recommend making a copy of the repo first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that your unpushed commits are still there, it's just that branch references have been lost.

The best you can do to recover them is the following:

- Copy the whole directory, you never know
- run a `git fsck`
- Look in the [reflog](http://gitolite.com/concepts/reflog.html) for your last commit. It's very likely to be the last branch tip
- Create a branch on it: `git checkout -b laststate`
- Save uncommitted files apart from the working dir.
- Reset hard to the last branch tip SHA1 `git reset --hard <sha1>`
- Put back your uncommitted changes

---

So seeing your edits your repo is really screwed up.

The HEAD is invalid ref, now your last chance is to set it to `origin/master`

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

should fix things and set your HEAD back.

Comment: I only have a couple of changes locally that are not committed, and luckily I have no unpushed committed changes - I'd just done a push before the outage. So I can easily save those two files separately if it makes things easier than copying my entire multi-Gb local repo?

Comment: @John you can just copy those files to some other folder, recreate your git repo (clone it from master) and copy the files over back to that local clone.

Comment: @eis can I do that on my existing repo dir so it doesn't download all the files from scratch? What would that command look like?

Comment: @John I think you need to recreate from scratch, meaning in practice redownloading the repo by using git clone. It does seem your local repo is quite broken. Somebody else might have still other suggestions, but that's what I'd do.

Comment: I would try to put some valid head, if you still have one, into your `.git/HEAD`, e.g. `ref: refs/heads/master` (literally look into the `.git/refs/heads/` directory and write that line into the `.git/HEAD` file.) If you don't have any valid head, take a commit hash from your remote repository and put it into a temporary head file, e.g. `.git/refs/heads/recover-tmp` and then set the `HEAD` to it. Hopefully you can then continue with the instructions given by @CharlesB.

Comment: One thing you can try before re-cloning upstream is to just fetch it into your damaged repo -- if the filesystem has lost your local refs, it may not have lost your object packs.  Then you can fsck to be sure what you have is consistent and with any luck you're about two adds and a commit from home.

Comment: Well I ended up having to do a clean clone. However even when I deleted my original .get and replacing with a copy of the .git from the new clone, it was STILL broken. Does git store any state anywhere else at all?